# Can't pass authorization with AJAX request on JS

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, authorization

I'm trying to send a basic AJAX request through browser console. The task demands an authorization so I've got a login and a secret key for the request.
My code:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.mindbox.cloud/v3/operations/sync?endpointId=hh.ru&operation=get.user', true, 'login', 'secret key');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
xhr.send();
console.log('status:', xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
console.log('xhr.response:', xhr.response);
```

the problem is that everytime I get the 401 error and a response from server:

`Authorization header is incorrect. Correct header example:\r\nAuthorization: Mindbox secretKey=\"PUT_YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE\`

Can anyone kindly help me here? I've tried hard to find some info about authorization headers but couldn't achieve anything valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the header just like you did with `Content-type`

```js
req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Mindbox secretKey=\"PUT_YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE\"');
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It helped. Now it seems like I can apply my secret key but smth wrong with it. The server responds `{"status":"ProtocolError","errorMessage":"Access denied.","errorId":"343dbbf1-9f43-408e-84cd-2f6b51c434ad","httpStatusCode":403}`

Comment: Most likely you're doing something you're not allowed to do with the service. I'd recommend you check their documentation to see if there's anything you missed. If not, you might want to reach out to their support. If my answer solved your problem, please click the check to accept it as the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the problem is with the service and that my secret key doesn't have rights for the request. I tried to send the request with Postman but I got the same 403 error.  Anyway, thanks a lot for helping!